# Jquery .next() not working

Tags: jquery

I have table structure with the following.

```
<td class="backgroundimage"><img src="02.jpg" border="0" class="foregroundimage"></td>
<td class="backgroundimage"><img src="03.jpg" border="0" class="foregroundimage"></td>
```

I am trying to get each img src within my table by doing this.

```
$('.backgroundImage').each(function(index){
    var oldImage = $(this).next("img").attr('src');

    alert(oldImage);
});
```

This alerts undefined. What have I done wrong? Am I using `.next()` wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - `.next()` looks at the next sibling. And none of your `td` elements have an `img` sibling.

You probably wanted to use `$(this).find('img')` or simply `$('img', this)`.

Depending on what you need to do the following might also do the job:

```
$('.backgroundimage img').each(function() {
    var oldImage = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
$(this).next("img")
```

You should do:

```
$(this).find("img")
```

Hope this helps